# What is the relation between the whatwg's Loader spec, dynamic import proposal and <script type='module'>?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

How are the three above related? This is my understanding so far: `ES6 spec` defines the syntax for `ES6 modules`, but it doesn't specify how to load those modules. The only way to use them in browser environment is through module scripts. There is also a dynamic import operator proposal that lets you conditionally load modules from scripts and module scripts. So, does the Loader spec say how the browser loads module scripts in the background? Or maybe it says how the `import()` operator behaves in different environments? Or it is something else and not related to the above two? If the Loader spec says how `import()` behaves in different environments, how that relates to the way browser loads modules used by `<script type="module">`? Are there two specs on how module loading works, based on whether it is by the dynamic import operator or `<script type="module">`?

Answer (score 3):

You are basically correct. The ECMAScript standard does not specify how module names are to be resolved: it's up to the execution environment to define it. This was first specified in [ECMA-262 6th Ed., §15.2.1.17](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule); later specifications contain similar language.

In a browser, module references in `import` statements will be treated as relative URIs and loaded directly, assuming they start with `/`, `./` or `../` (which is meant to maintain forward compatibility). This behaviour is specified in [the HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#resolve-a-module-specifier) ([WHATWG HTML LS 2019-11-26 §8.1.3.8](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system)).

A script contained in (or referenced by) a `<script type="module">` tag is parsed as a module and executed when the entire document markup has been parsed. There isn't that much difference from normal `<script defer>`, except that the `import` and `export` statements are now available. `<script type="module">` is also described in HTML specification ([WHATWG HTML LS 2019-11-26 §4.12.1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element))

The `import()` pseudo-function returns a promise which resolves to the module specified as its operand. Module names are resolved in exactly the same way as in the `import` statement. As of this writing, it is not standardised yet, but is expected to become part of ECMA-262 11th Ed. (ECMAScript 2020). You can read the [draft specification](https://tc39.es/proposal-dynamic-import/) or see the [proposal repository](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/).

The [WHATWG Loader](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/) is an abandoned specification also covering dynamic import, and also accommodating more advanced features, like on-the-fly translation of foreign scripts or assigning meaning to 'bare' module names (which are currently not usable, as explained above). It exists only as an incomplete specification and to my knowledge has never been actually implemented.

Comment: Might also want to mention [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps)

Answer (score 1):

**Using `<script />` with** *type=module*

This is not strictly *dynamic* `import()` related:

> the browser will treat the inline or external script as an ECMAScript
>   module.

```
<script type="module">
  import {addTextToBody} from './utils.mjs';

  addTextToBody('Modules are pretty cool.');
</script>
```

Ref: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

**Dynamic import()**

> With static import, your entire module graph needs to be downloaded
>   and executed before your main code can run. Sometimes, you don’t want
>   to load a module up-front, but rather on-demand, only when you need it
>   — when the user clicks a link or a button, for example. This improves
>   the initial load-time performance. Dynamic import() makes this

```
<script type="module">
  (async () => {
    const moduleSpecifier = './lib.mjs';
    const {repeat, shout} = await import(moduleSpecifier);
    repeat('hello');
    // → 'hello hello'
    shout('Dynamic import in action');
    // → 'DYNAMIC IMPORT IN ACTION!'
  })();
</script>
```

Ref: https://v8.dev/features/modules#other-features